# google maps api v3 marker symbol circle pixel diameter?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, marker

Using google maps API v3.

I want to create a marker that is circle, so I use the following (only relevant code is shown):

```
var icn = { fillColor: "#0000FF",
            fillOpacity: 1.0, 
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE, 
            scale: 4,
            strokeColor: "#0000FF",
            strokeWeight: 1.0 };

var m = new google.maps.Marker({ map: my_map, position: p, icon: icn } );
```

Works great...

But how does one calculate (or control) the diameter of the circle (in pixels)?  According to the API documentation:

> scale - number The amount by which the symbol is scaled in size. For
>   symbol markers, this defaults to 1; after scaling, the symbol may be
>   of any size. For symbols on a polyline, this defaults to the stroke
>   weight of the polyline; after scaling, the symbol must lie inside a
>   square 22 pixels in size centered at the symbol's anchor.

Can someone (google) please clarify:

a) For a CIRCLE symbol, if strokeWeight is 1.0 and scale is 4, then circle diameter is what in pixels?  Is there some magic formula for creating circles of a specific pixel diameter?

b) Is the maximum size of a circle restricted to 22 pixels?  Does not seem to be the case as I can scale to almost any size -- again, clarification -- is the 22 pixel limit only for symbols on a polyline?

Answer (score 1):

The path of the built-in circle is:

```
 M -1,0 A 1,1 0 0 0 1,0 1,1 0 0 0 -1,0 z
```

....so the diameter of the path is 2px

The stroke will half overlap the fill, so you may use the following formula for the built-in CIRCLE to calculate the diameter of the complete symbol(including the stroke):

```
(scale*2)+strokeWeight//where strokeWeight defaults to scale
```

for your example it will result in a diameter of 9px

The 22px-restriction is related to symbols on a Polyline([IconSequences](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#IconSequence)), when you use the symbols as Marker there is no restriction.